# How do I debug the typescript code React Native Project in vscode(visual Studio Code) react-native tool?

Tags: debugging, react-native, visual-studio-code, typescript2.0

I can debug the built js code, in the ts or tsx code set breakpoints, suggesting: Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found (source map problem?)

[my github repository](https://github.com/yahue/TimeTop)